# mariadb galera cluster stop one node automaticly

Tags: mysql, mariadb, galera

I have  Mariadb galera cluster. I have 4 nodes. but When one node become slow, it stop itself automaticly. that's the error. What should I do?

```
151030 17:17:14 [Note] WSREP: view((empty))
151030 17:17:14 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: closed
151030 17:17:14 [Warning] WSREP: 0x7f8cab043c40 down context(s) not set
151030 17:17:14 [Warning] WSREP: Failed to send SYNC signal: -107 (Transport endpoint is not connected)
151030 17:17:14 [Note] WSREP: New COMPONENT: primary = no, bootstrap = no, my_idx = 0, memb_num = 1
151030 17:17:14 [Note] WSREP: Flow-control interval: [16, 16]
151030 17:17:14 [Note] WSREP: Received NON-PRIMARY.
151030 17:17:14 [Note] WSREP: Shifting JOINED -> OPEN (TO: 55363)
151030 17:17:14 [Note] WSREP: Received self-leave message.
151030 17:17:14 [Note] WSREP: Flow-control interval: [0, 0]
151030 17:17:14 [Note] WSREP: Received SELF-LEAVE. Closing connection.
151030 17:17:14 [Note] WSREP: Shifting OPEN -> CLOSED (TO: 55363)
151030 17:17:14 [Note] WSREP: RECV thread exiting 0: Success
151030 17:17:14 [Note] WSREP: recv_thread() joined.
151030 17:17:14 [Note] WSREP: Closing replication queue.
151030 17:17:14 [Note] WSREP: Closing slave action queue.
151030 17:17:14 [ERROR] WSREP: Local state seqno (55362) is greater than group seqno (55333): states diverged. Aborting to avoid potential data loss. Remove '/mnt/mariadb/kohadata/mysql//grastate.dat' file and restart if you wish to continue. (FATAL)
     at galera/src/replicator_str.cpp:state_transfer_required():33
151030 17:17:14 [Note] WSREP: applier thread exiting (code:8)
151030 17:17:14 [Note] WSREP: starting shutdown
151030 17:17:14 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Normal shutdown

151030 17:17:14 [Note] WSREP: Stop replication
151030 17:17:16 [Note] WSREP: rollbacker thread exiting
151030 17:17:16 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
151030 17:17:16 [Note] WSREP: dtor state: CONNECTED
151030 17:17:17 [Note] WSREP: mon: entered 4827 oooe fraction 0 oool fraction 0
151030 17:17:18 [Note] WSREP: mon: entered 4827 oooe fraction 0.00103584 oool fraction 0
151030 17:17:18 [Note] WSREP: mon: entered 8943 oooe fraction 0 oool fraction 0.000111819
151030 17:17:18 [Note] WSREP: cert index usage at exit 0
151030 17:17:18 [Note] WSREP: cert trx map usage at exit 0
151030 17:17:18 [Note] WSREP: deps set usage at exit 0
151030 17:17:18 [Note] WSREP: avg deps dist 3.22926
151030 17:17:18 [Note] WSREP: avg cert interval 0.0052105
151030 17:17:18 [Note] WSREP: cert index size 2
151030 17:17:18 [Note] WSREP: Service thread queue flushed.
151030 17:17:18 [Note] WSREP: wsdb trx map usage 0 conn query map usage 0
151030 17:17:18 [Note] WSREP: MemPool(LocalTrxHandle): hit ratio: 0.866667, misses: 4, in use: 0, in pool: 4
151030 17:17:18 [Note] WSREP: MemPool(SlaveTrxHandle): hit ratio: 0.994795, misses: 25, in use: 0, in pool: 25
151030 17:17:18 [Warning] WSREP: Waiting for 28 items to be fetched.
```

I have another error

```
151030 17:44:28 [Note] WSREP: 1.0 (koha-db58): State transfer from 2.0 (koha-db59) complete.
151030 17:44:28 [Note] WSREP: Member 1.0 (koha-db58) synced with group.
151030 17:48:13 [Warning] WSREP: last inactive check more than PT1.5S ago (PT1.54315S), skipping check
151030 17:48:15 [Warning] WSREP: last inactive check more than PT1.5S ago (PT2.09676S), skipping check
151030 17:48:22 [Warning] WSREP: last inactive check more than PT1.5S ago (PT2.0889S), skipping check
151030 17:48:25 [Warning] WSREP: last inactive check more than PT1.5S ago (PT1.59553S), skipping check
151030 17:48:28 [Warning] WSREP: last inactive check more than PT1.5S ago (PT3.07406S), skipping check
 151030 17:57:17 [Warning] WSREP: last inactive check more than PT1.5S ago (PT18.6297S), skipping check
```

Comment: Increase some wsrep timeouts.  (Sorry, I don't know which one(s).)  How far apart are the nodes (network latency, that is)?